# qDebug Console output with Timestamp

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, timestamp, database-connection

I wrote a qt small console utility for testing database connectivity, the code block is:

```
db.setHostName("hostIP");    
db.setDatabaseName("name");    
db.setUserName("uid");    
db.setPassword("pw");    
db.setPort(1521);

while(true)
{
    if (db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<"OPEN";
        db.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"YOU MESSED UP "<<db.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

the console output when the database is down or cannot be connected can be seen in the console output, what I want is to tee the timestamp also.

Is there a way to print the event timestamp on the console along with the qDebug messages ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure you can. For doing so you can use QTime class, i.e.:

```
qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString() << "YOU MESSED UP "<< db.lastError().text();
```

Or, in the same way you can print out the date and time information with using `QDateTime::currentDateTime()` function.

Comment: QTime("15:33:05") YOU MESSED UP  "ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
Unable to logon" 

Thanx, it solved the problem... u did a lil typo though :)
it will be QTime.

Comment: @AmarjitBiswas, please take a look on the updated answer. I have improved it a little bit.

Answer (score 16):

You could install a message handler and print out the timestamp before every message. See the documentation of [`qInstallMessageHandler`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) for this.
With this solution you don't have to add `QTimer::currentTime()` on every call of `qDebug()`.

Comment: Any way to do something similar in Qt 4.8 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux, you can set `QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN` environment variable,as explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html):

`QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN="[%{type}] %{appname} (%{file}:%{line}) - %{message}"`